# makefile for openmp by g++ ---- It is not working

Tags: makefile, g++, openmp

I want to use a makefile for my code which is going to use openmp. My source files are compiled and linked without any error. But when I run it, it uses just one processor, even though I adjust their number by for instance export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2.

The makefile is shown in the following.  I would be grateful if somebody could please help me.

Best

```html
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))

CC = g++
DEBUG = -g

INTEL=icc
ifeq ($(notdir $(CC)),$(INTEL))
CCFLAGS=-openmp -lm -lstdc++
else
CCFLAGS=-fopenmp -lm -lstdc++
endif

LD_FLAGS :=-fopenmp -Wall $(DEBUG)
#CC_FLAGS := -Wall -c $(DEBUG)


MAIN: $(OBJ_FILES)
 $(CC) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $@ $^

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
 $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY: clean

clean:
 rm -f $(OBJ_FILES) *.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your defined variable `CCFLAGS` doesn't match the variable you're using `CC_FLAGS` in the actual compilation rules. When you clean up and run `make` do the compilation lines actually show the flags you set being passed? I'd expect they shouldn't, unless the code you have here isn't a direct copy of what you're running.

For ease of debugging, could you copy and paste a terminal transcript showing the compilation and linking happening?

Comment: You are right.. It was a huge mistake! Now, it is working very well.... Thank you very much for your time and your great help...